# Reading Activity Arguments In a Bookmark Before Resuming

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm building an asp.net mvc app which uses Windows workflow and I'm in need to resume a bookmark depending on an argument inside my custom activity (filled by the creator of the workflow), unfortunately all samples I've found get the value of the Argument after the bookmark is resumed.

is this even possible?

(I tried an extension, but while it's super useful I can't use it now as it runs when the workflow is resumed and before the next bookmark is resumed)

Thanks in advance!

Geo

Answer (score 1):

The [BookmarkCallback delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.bookmarkcallback.aspx), when called, passes in a [NativeActivityContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.nativeactivitycontext.aspx).  With this context you can read and write to any In/Out/InOutArguments defined on the Activity.  If you do not remove the bookmark during the execution of this delegate, the workflow will remain idled.

How it works would be:

- An Activity creates a bookmark
- Workflow is idled
- You call ResumeBookmark on the workflow
- BookmarkCallback is called in your activity
- Your Activity checks some in/out/inoutarguments and the value passed into ResumeBookmark

  - If you want to resume, remove the bookmark
  - If you do not want to resume, leave the bookmark and return